# Substring within string

Tags: ruby, string

I need to extract from an input everything that is after a parameter.

- Input: `"-a Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate"`
- Criteria: Need to extract everything after `-c`.

My output should be `Chocolate`. I tried `split`, `scan` and the output returned two elements. Can anyone help me with this requirement?

Also, request you to let me know how to handle if my input is `"-a Apple -c Chocolate -b Ball"`.

Comment: So for `"-a Apple -c Chocolate -b Ball"`, you want `" Chocolate -b Ball"` (everything after `-c`), right?

Comment: no. If my input is "-a Apple -c Chocolate -b Ball", I still wanted to read only -c value as Chocolate. My concern was the position of the -c parameter in the input string.

Comment: That is not everything after `-c`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) library to do this:

```
require 'optparse'

arguments = { }

opts = OptionParser.new do |parser|
  parser.on('-a=s') do |v|
    arguments[:a] = v
  end
  parser.on('-b=s') do |v|
    arguments[:b] = v
  end
  parser.on('-c=s') do |v|
    arguments[:c] = v
  end
end

opts.parse("-a Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate".split)

arguments
# => {:a=>"Apple", :b=>"Ball", :c=>"Chocolate"}
```

It's quite flexible in how it works, so you can define a lot of options and how they're interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want everything after the marker (-c):

```
s = "-a Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate"
index = s.index('-c')
everything_after = s[(index + 2)..-1]
puts everything_after # => Chocolate
```

If you want to parse the arguments:

require 'optparse'

```
opts = OptionParser.new do |parser|
  parser.on('-a=s') do |v|
  end
  parser.on('-b=s') do |v|
  end
  parser.on('-c=s') do |v|
    puts "-c is #{v}"
  end
end

opts.parse("-a Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate".split(/\s/))
```

(you will need to specify all the flags, otherwise the parser will choke)

Or you could simply match the content with a Regexp. 
I think you are looking for: <ANYTHING><FLAG><ANYTHING BUT DASH><ANYTHING> where <FLAG> is '-c '

```
s.match(/\A.*-c\s([^-]*).*\z/) do |match|
  p match[1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is the command line arguments passed to a ruby script, try:

`ARGV[ARGV.index("-c") + 1]`

Explanation:

`ARGV` is an `array` that includes all the arguments passed to a `ruby` script. `Array#index` returns the index of the first object in self.

Refer to [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "-a Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate"
```

**One way: calculate an index**

```
marker = "-c"
s[s.index(marker)+marker.size+1..-1]
  #=> "Chocolate" 

marker = "-b"
s[s.index(marker)+marker.size+1..-1]
  #=> "Ball -c Chocolate" 

marker = "-a"
s[s.index(marker)+marker.size+1..-1]
  #=> "Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate"
```

**Another way: use a regex**

```
`\K` in the regex below means "forget everything matched so far".

marker = "-c"
s[/#{marker}\s+\K.*/]
  #=> "Chocolate" 

marker = "-b"
s[/#{marker}\s+\K.*/]
  #=> "Ball -c Chocolate" 

marker = "-a"
s[/#{marker}\s+\K.*/]
  #=> "Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate"
```

Consider the regex for one of these markers.

```
marker = "-a"
r = /
    #{marker}   # match the contents of the variable 'marker'
    \s+         # match > 0 whitespace chars
    \K          # forget everything matched so far
    .*          # match the rest of the line
    /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> /
  #   -a          # match the contents of the variable 'marker'
  #   \s+         # match > 0 whitespace chars
  #   \K          # forget everything matched so far
  #   .*          # match the rest of the line
  #   /x 
s[r]
  #=> "Apple -b Ball -c Chocolate"
```

**But if you really want just the text between markers**

I will construct a hash with markers as keys and text as values. First, we will use the following regex to split the string.

```
r = /
      \s*     # match >= 0 spaces
      \-      # match hypen
      (       # begin capture group 1
        [a-z] # match marker
      )       # end capture group 1
        \s*   # match >= 0 spaces
      /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

h = s.split(r).drop(1).each_slice(2).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"Apple", "b"=>"Ball", "c"=>"Chocolate"}
```

With this hash we can retrieve the text for each marker.

```
h["a"]
  #=> "Apple" 
h["b"]
  #=> "Ball" 
h["c"]
  #=> "Chocolate"
```

The steps to create the hash are as follows.

```
a = s.split(r)
  #=> ["", "a", "Apple", "b", "Ball", "c", "Chocolate"]
```

Notice that, by putting `[a-z]` within a capture group in the regex, `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` are included in the array `a`. (See [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split), third paragraph.)

```
b = a.drop(1)
  #=> ["a", "Apple", "b", "Ball", "c", "Chocolate"] 
c = b.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["a", "Apple", "b", "Ball", "c", "Chocolate"]:each_slice(2)>
```

We can see the elements of the enumerator `c` by converting it to an array:

```
c.to_a
  #=> [["a", "Apple"], ["b", "Ball"], ["c", "Chocolate"]]
```

Lastly,

```
c.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"Apple", "b"=>"Ball", "c"=>"Chocolate"}
```